# Problem using cp command with negation (!) on crontab

Tags: bash, cron, ubuntu-14.04

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/tpd
cp -pr !(edc|dti|swb|audio|blog|buy|dpt|dpt.git|dpt-staging-server|dti_old|images|images2|images_linkshare|smarty-3.1.30|swb.com|swb.com.temp|talent|template_c|video|yout|yout-admin|All_About_Your_Canine_Friend.pdf|Canine_Cuisine.pdf|definitiveguide.pdf|GroomingYourDogAtHome-FreeReport.pdf|HowToStopYourPuppyOrOlderDogFromBiting.pdf|Network Merchants API.pdf|SuperDogsandPuppies.pdf|TopDogs.pdf|UltimateBreedGuide.pdf|10CommonProblemsofAdultDogs.pdf|10CommonProblemsofPuppies.pdf|45commonlyaskedquestionsondoggrooming.pdf|g.tar.gz|h.tar.gz|dti_back.tar.gz|Canine_Cuisine.zip|deluxe_version.zip|h.zip|StyleXPInstallMale.zip|UltimateBreedGuide.zip|videotranscripts.zip|101ways.zip)  weeklyBackup
tar -cvf weeklyBackup.tar.gz weeklyBackup
rm -rf weeklyBackup
```

I am taking a weekly backup for only some selected files and this is the script that I am using. It works perfectly when running manually but when I am entering this is a crontab, it returns an error line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: That's not negation, it's an extglob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `!(name1|name2|name3)` is what's called an "extglob". This is an optional extension to bash, not enabled by default.

To enable this syntax, you need to run (as a prior line in your script):

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Presumably your dotfiles are already doing this for interactive shells, which is why the syntax works for you out-of-the-box. (Also ensure that if your script is invoked from cron with `sh scriptname`, `bash scriptname` is used instead, or the code is modified to honor the shebang).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: But why was this working when giving manually and the problem is only when we give it on crontab?

Comment: @nj_Graffiti, I describe that in the answer: "*Presumably your dotfiles are already doing this for interactive shells*". Even if it's not in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, there's still `/etc/profile` and the files it sources.